# JavaScript - My function only triggers once while being called several times in a loop

Tags: javascript, regex, loops

I have this function :

```js
  function simplifyString (string)
  {
    var charsToFind = new Array(/[áàâãä]/g, /[éèêë]/g, /[íìîï]/g, /[óòôõö]/g, /[úùûü]/g, /ç/g, /[-  \'&_]/g),
        charsToReplace = new Array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'c', '');

    string = string.toLowerCase();

    for (i = 0; i < charsToFind.length; i++)
    {
      string = string.replace(charsToFind[i], charsToReplace[i]);
    }

    return string;
  }
```

And I use it inside a loop, like this :

```js
for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
  var value = simplifyString(objects[i].innerText);
  
  console.log(value);
  console.log(i);
 }
```

Objects variable contains an array of elements.

Console will only show me the inner text of the first element, and `i` will display the length of my array - 1.

If I remove the loop of my function, console will show me inner text of every object and the correct serie of numbers.

I don't quite understand this behaviour, any help?

Comment: you are potentially leaking `i` into different scopes.

Comment: Can you please show more code.

Comment: defintiely i being reassigned! in the simplifyString function. If you just do var 1 = 0, I think you'll be ok. No var sets it to a global variable.

Comment: @MaheerAli there's not much more to show. I just get an array of objects with JQuery : `var objects = $('span')`

Comment: Yep, you're right guys, I declared `i` inside my function and it works now. Didn't think of that. Thank you very much, it was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
for (i = 0; i < charsToFind.length; i++)
```

TO...

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
for (var i = 0; i < charsToFind.length; i++)
```

OR...

```
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
for (let i = 0; i < charsToFind.length; i++)
```

*Note on browser support: In IE 11 "let variables are not bound separately to each iteration of for loops"*
[Caniuse - let](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let).

You are currently declaring `i`, in both `for` loops, without an identifier `var, let, const` so it is being assigned to the same `i` property on the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) rather than declaring an new locally scoped variable. The `for` loop inside `simplifyString (string)` is assigning a new value to the same `i` as the first `for` loop and screwing everything up.

* As mentioned in comments, this how you could use `reduce()` to make your code more readable, minimize unnecessary [side-effects/mutations](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0) and couple your `tests` directly with their replacement `values` to avoid some confusion...

```
var charReplacements = [
   { test: /[áàâãä]/g,   value: 'a' },
   { test: /[éèêë]/g,    value: 'e' },
   { test: /[íìîï]/g,    value: 'i' },
   { test: /[óòôõö]/g,   value: 'o' },
   { test: /[úùûü]/g,    value: 'u' },
   { test: /ç/g,         value: 'c' },
   { test: /[-  \'&_]/g, value: ''  }
];

function simplifyString (string) {    
    return charReplacements
              .reduce((str, {test, value}) => 
                 str.replace(test, value)
              , string);
}
```

NOTE: If you're running this over large datasets I'd ask someone smarter than me how do this with a few lines of regex, which would be much more efficient than iterating over the replacers

Comment: I actually much prefer to use the newer Array methods ( [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) .etc )  whenever possible now. Syntactically they are much cleaner and more readable, at a slight performance cost *(negligible over small data sets)*. You should take a look at those when you get a chance.

Comment: I used `for` in my function because I need the index in order to make my two arrays match. In the second loop, there was no particular reason for me to use it, indeed. A `forEach` loop would definitly do the job. I've heard about map() and reduce() but never digged further about them. I definitly will. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Wow, I love this. This looks way more modern, professional and readable while being also shorter. I was actually making some tests with arrays and reduce()/map() loops until I saw your post. I'll use this and try to code using those tools from now on. I tend to stick on what I know because it's more comfortable and new things can seem confusing to me, but this will definitly help. I also learned about arrow functions, so really, thanks for that.

Comment: Great! Happy I could help and think thats a good direction. You do have to be careful with some of these newer language features depending on the environment you're in (especially destructuring `{test, value}`). These 2 courses are pretty great introductions to manipulating complex data sets in similar ways... [Asynchronous Programming in JavaScript (with Rx.js Observables)](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/asynchronous-javascript/) and [Advanced Asynchronous JavaScript](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/advanced-async-js/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with how your loop counters are scoped. 
Instead of doing

```
for (i = 0; ...)
```

You should declare your loop counter as

```
for (let i = 0;...)
```

So that it is scoped to your loop block.

If you declare your loop variable as just 'i=0', then 'i' has a global scope. In this scenario, the 'i' you are using in your simplifyString loop is the same 'i' that you are using in the loop that calls simplifyString! Since simplifyString increments 'i' after you call it the first time, the invoking loop terminates prematurely.